# Where are the downloadable Rails generators?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-generation, scaffolding

When I run...

```
$ script/generate
```

I get a list of installed generators and a message saying "More are available at http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/AvailableGenerators." However, the indicated wiki page says "This topic does not exist yet."

Does there exist some central repository of downloadable Rails generators?

In particular, I'd like one that creates the Rails scaffolding, but uses Haml instead of ERB.

It would also be neat if it would generate the Test::Unit tests but using the Shoulda enhancements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That wiki was a wonderful resource back in the day, but it's long gone.  I threw up a [archive containing that page](http://www.reality.com/roberts/markus/software/ruby/rails/wiki/AvailableGenerators.textile) from when the wiki started wobbling.  It's dated but you can at least see what was there.

As for now, look for gems (especially plugins) to provide the generators rather than expecting them as isolated resources.  The `gems` command can be used to find whats available.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of plugins come with their own generators.  The one that springs to mind is restful_authentication because I have used it quite a bit.

Edit: Did you google [here](http://speakmy.name/2009/02/rails-scaffold-generator-that-uses-rspec-haml-and-factorygirl/)?

Answer (score 0):

There's [Rails Boost](http://www.railsboost.com/), which is a template generator.  In fact, the template you want has already [been generated](http://www.railsboost.com/templates/949) -- that one uses HAML and Shoulda.